# Сокрытие имен c помощью type alias

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Пример:

```
struct A {};
struct B { using A = A; };

int main()
{
    B b;
}
```

Clang компилирует это. GCC выдает ошибку ([пример](https://wandbox.org/permlink/W8E2m00CtvVqe6BJ)):

> declaration of 'using A = struct A' changes meaning of 'A'

В [стандарте](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.hiding) написано:

> <s>If a class name ([class.name]) or enumeration name ([dcl.enum]) and a variable, data member, function, or enumerator are declared in the same declarative region (in any order) with the same name (**excluding declarations made visible via using-directives** ([basic.lookup.unqual])), the class or enumeration name is hidden wherever the variable, data member, function, or enumerator name is visible.</s>

*P.S. Спасибо Vlad From Moscow*

> A name N used in a class S shall refer to the same declaration in its context and when re-evaluated in the completed scope of S. No diagnostic is required for a violation of this rule

Получается, у GCC - некорректное поведение?

Comment: Ну здесь объявляется т.н. type alias. А это не то же самое, что "using-directive". Кроме того, тот же GCC жуёт эту конструкцию с опцией `-fpermissive` (но это черная магия всё же). По поводу соответствия стандарту сказать затрудняюсь сейчас

Comment: @GeorgyFirsov, Вы правы, прошу прощения за неточности в описании. Сейчас поправлю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Синтаксис `using A = A;` это красивый синтаксис для команды `typedef`. Она позволяет использовать синоним типа в другом пространстве имён. Это аналог :

```
struct B {
  typedef A A ;
  } ;
```

Правила не позволяют переопределять типы, уже созданные в данном пространстве класса или структуры.

Стандарт :

> In a given non-class scope, a typedef specifier can be used to redefine the name of any type declared in that scope to refer to the type to which it already refers. [ Example:

```
typedef struct s { /∗ ... ∗/ } s;
typedef int I;
typedef int I;
typedef I I; // OK
```

> In a given class scope, a typedef specifier can be used to redefine
> any class-name declared in that scope that is not also a typedef-name
> to refer to the type to which it already refers. [ Example:

```
struct S {
  typedef struct A { } A; // OK
  typedef struct B B;     // OK
  typedef A A;            // error
  };
```

Компилятор так и намекает вам про ошибку :

```
error: declaration of ‘typedef struct A B::A’ changes meaning of ‘A’ [-fpermissive]
```

То есть нельзя внутри структуры B тип A называть типом A ( *структуры B* ).

Подсказка: чтобы подправить разное поведение компиляторов, **using** можно использовать указывая из какого пространства имён вы хотите взять синоним :

```
struct A {};
struct B {
  using A = :: A ;
  } ;
```

Я думаю, что в GCC ошибка. Так как новый синоним типа `B :: A` ещё не создан, а `typedef` уже говорит, что он есть.

Стандарт :

> In particular, it does not define a new type and it shall not appear in the type-id.

```
using cell = pair<void*, cell*>; // ill-formed
```